# Flask pytest testclient failing with response code 404

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am running test for my flask application which are failing with 404 response code.

Please note that my flask application works fine when I run it with `python3 src/serve.py`. All the endpoints are working perfectly. But when I run the tests, I get 404.

This is the test file -

```
from root import app
import pytest
import json
import config

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_get_paragraph(client):
    response = client.get('/get')
    
    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = json.loads(response.data)
    assert 'paragraphs' in data
    assert data['paragraphs'] != ''
    assert isinstance(data['paragraphs'], str)
```

This is serve.py

```
from flask import request, jsonify
import requests

import db_handler
import es_handler
import config
import model 

from redis_cache import RedisCache
from root import *
    
with app.app_context():
    db_handler.drop_db(db)
    db_handler.create_db(db)

es_handler.init_elasticsearch(es, config.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX)

@app.route('/get')
def get_paragraph():
    response = requests.get(config.PARAGRAPH_API_URL)
    if response.status_code == 404:
     return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to fetch paragraph'})

    paragraph = response.text.strip()
    # paragraph = "As I stop in the valley of shadow and death I look at gangster's paradise ferrari and realise there's nothin left"

    es_handler.add_para_to_index(es, config.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX, paragraph)
    db_handler.add_paragraph(db, model.Paragraph, paragraph)

    return jsonify({'paragraphs': paragraph})
```

This is root.py -

```
from flask import Flask

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from redis import Redis
import config

# App config
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
        user=config.DB_USER,
        passwd=config.DB_PASS,
        host=config.DB_HOST,
        port=config.DB_PORT,
        db=config.DB_NAME)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = config.SECRET_KEY

# Database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

File structure is as follows -

```
/src
/src/serve.py
/src/root.py
/src/tests/unit/test_serve.py
```

I am running tests using the command - `pytest src/tests/unit/test_serve.py`